# My regex match positive real numbers doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am reading from a TextBox in C# and I want to make sure that only real positive values are allowed (including integers).
i.e. 1, 23, 23., 23.0, 23.42, etc.
The Regex I am using is:

`[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*`

But C# does only let me type numbers and I can never put a period.

Thank you

Code:

```
    private static readonly Regex rgx_onlyPositiveReals = new Regex("[0-9]+\\.?[0-9]*"); 

    private void TextBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !IsSamplingRateAllowed(e.Text);

    }

    private static bool IsSamplingRateAllowed(string text)
    {
        if(rgx_onlyPositiveReals.IsMatch(text))
        {
            if(text.Equals(".") || float.Parse(text) <= 0.0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sampling Rate has to be positive.", "Wrong Sampling Frequency Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Show us the actual source code in a form that we can run please.  Likely you have some minor typo or formatting error.

Comment: Start with a regex of `.*` and see if that works.  I suspect something isn't hooked up right.  Your regex is too permissive, if anything, and should allow your numbers, unless I missed something.

Comment: That gives the same result @zzxyz

Comment: @TheBosco - Likely you've done something in your razor, js, or something else, that's forbidding the `.`.  Alternately, the wrong C# function is getting called for the input event.

Comment: I think you probably meant to tag WPF instead of ASP.NET, by the way.  In which case I'd recommend pasting the XAML that declares your textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of things this input box is supposed to only contain the number and no other text; in this case I would avoid the regular expression altogether.

Given that you're parsing the regex match result into a `float` anyway, it might make more sense to try parsing the input as a `float` directly which has the added benefits of allowing any valid positive `float` that can be parsed in the first place, it also allows entering the number in any other valid formats supported by `float.Parse/float.TryParse` e.g. scientific notation `"1E5"` == `100000f` or commas `"1,500"` == `1500f` (depending on the culture) without any additional effort.

```
private static bool IsSamplingRateAllowed(string text)
{
    float number;
    return float.TryParse(text, out number) && number >= 0.0f;
}
```

Unless this data is being used for some external process as a `string` with additional restrictions on the format (which seems unlikely and is worth including in the question if that is the case), then if it isn't already, I'd recommend separating this input box from any other information and have users enter the number and only the number directly into the box. If you need to collect other information from the user you can add other input boxes and controls as necessary (which can also simplify validation for other pieces of information).

Answer (score 0):

[Give this a try](https://regex101.com/r/HbuBoe/1)

The pattern is `^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]*`

In C# you can prefix your string with @ which makes it easier to read a regex. It results in the following:

`"\\this \\is \\the \\same"` == `@"\this \is \the \same"`

Comment: Did not work. I get the same result. I am trying to consider what other things would forbid it from happening, but to be honest I am fairly new to WPF so there's not much I could have changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below Regex

```
^\d*[.]?\d*$
```

<kbd>**[Demo Fiddle](http://rubular.com/r/VB1qFLV8gj)**</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Do you want to add + Sign before?

Comment: optional + sign would be great. I think. Its upto OP.

Comment: @Gauravsa Positive number doesn't need `+` symbol indicate the positive integer. Also, User doesn't require it seems. Still if you wants to be add then go for `^[+]?\d*[.]?\d*$`